# How to debug a transform script in ServiceNow?

Tags: debugging, servicenow

> I have written a transform script in SN.Its not performing as it should be.So 
>   i just want to debug the script.So please suggest the ways to debug transform 
>   script in SN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you debug other scripts. Add gs.info/warning/error or add it directly to the Transform Script's log through the variable 'log'.

Additionally, you could use the legacy function gs.print, but you need to turn on debugging first.

Read more on the [Fuji wiki](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Debugging_Tools_Best_Practices) or [Geneva documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/script/debugging/topic/p_Debugging.html)